# Al acceder con su nombre y contraseña, ¿como puedo controlar el acceso a las vistas? ¿Como se trabaja con Roles? ¿Como asigno roles?En asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, razor

He creado una funcion en el controller para loguerse, lo cual me funciona:

```
<HttpPost> _
Public Function Login(user As UserModel) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        If Isvalid(user.rut, user.password) Then
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.rut, user.RememberMe)
            Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
        Else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!")
        End If
    End If
    Return View(user)
End Function
```

mi pregunta, es como puedo controlar el acceso a las vistas, para que solo el usuario logueado pueda acceder. Tengo entendido que una de las formas de hacerlo es con  _, asignando roles, pero no se ocuparlo.

Answer (score 2):

A través del ActionResult del controlador con la clase [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
   [HttpGet]
        [Authorization(AccessLevel = new Usuario.TiposUsuario[] 
        { 
            Usuario.TiposUsuario.Admin,
            Usuario.TiposUsuario.UserBase
        })]
        public ActionResult Home(int? id)
        {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En ASP.NET MVC 5 y 6 puedes usar Entity Framework.
En el siguien link puedes ver como se trabaja con usuarios y roles.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97#content

En MVC 6 cada usuario puede tener uno o mas roles. Por ejemplo el usuario "Armando" puede tener el rol "Admin". Lo que significa que el usuario "Armando" es un administrador de la app. En el controlador puedes indicar las acciones y/o clases a las que puede tener acceso cada usuario (No en las vistas), por ejemplo escribes antes de una clase que va a ser usada solo por el administrador lo siguiente:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
 public class AdministradorController : Controller
    { ...
}
```